# CodedUI - To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process

Tags: coded-ui-tests

For creating a Build-Deploy-Test Workflow for my Wpf application, I ma using TFS Build definition and MTM to create Environment.

I am using following Steps:

I am Using LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml in Build Definition
In the Lab Process Settings, I have given the required details as:

**Environment**: I have created an environment using MTM on the VM 
in the environment I have added a Desktop Client(the same VM only) in the machines List

Please note that my Test Controller, agent, MTM all are on the VM only

**Build**: I have selected an existing build definition and it's working fine.

**Deploy**: I have specidfied command for application installation(running of msi file)
also, In the deploy section only, at the end I have specified a batch file where I am calling my CodedUI tests via command line(using VSTEST.CONSOLE.EXE)

**Test**: Not using it i.e. Not checked the "Run these Tests in Environment"

When I run this build definition, build creation, and installation are working fine but failes to run the codedui tests. Getting following error:

Error Message:
 Error calling Initialization method for test class CodedUITestProject1.AISTest: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestException: To run tests that interact with the desktop, you must set up the test agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Set Up Your Test Agent to Run Tests That Interact with the Desktop" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255012)
 If you are running the tests as part of your team build, you must also set up the build agent to run as an interactive process. For more information, see "How to: Configure and Run Scheduled Tests After Building Your Application" (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=254735)
 Stack Trace:
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.Initialize()
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestExtensionExecution.BeforeTestInitialize(Object sender, BeforeTestInitializeEventArgs e)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecution.RaiseBeforeTestInitialize(BeforeTestInitializeEventArgs args)
 at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestExecuter.RunInitializeMethod()
 Test Run Failed.

Also, I have made sure that test agent is configured as an interactive process.

Any Help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Ok version of tfs, vS, MTM, Controller, Agent and Browser please. Also is it running as part of a build?

Comment: Run Options? Interactive Process? Admin user ? OS? Screensaver Disabled? Are you using a settings file for the tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue got resolved after setting the build controller also to run as a interactive process.